# Values from a column that are related to ALL elements of another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to ask the following, given the next table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PyfY.png

How can I obtain the values in the column nom_adob that are related to ALL different values in the column nom_planta?

Comment: Why are you discarding `Vitaplant` and `PlantaVit`?

Comment: Sample output, please ?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please describe how the result set is determined.

Comment: The output is all the values from the column nom_adob (in this case the result is only Casadob) that have at least one relation with each value in nom_planta.

Comment: So I want to get all values from the nom_adob column that appear at least once related to ALL distinct values in the first column.

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables. Include logic in question narrative.